# Convert two columns to values from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

so I have the following table:

```
personID    grade   classID
   13          7    147
   13          7    456
   19          8    123
   19          8    789
   25          7    123
   25          7    456
   25          7    789
   82          8    147
   82          8    456
   155         7    456
   155         7    789
```

I would like to keep the grade column, but have the personID and classID be mapped to another table to get the personName and ClassName - each are different tables, but the one separate table with the person name also has person ID, and the one with the class name has the classID so it makes it easy.

The result table should still be 11 columns long, just replaced with the persons name and class name for each row.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this done with a join?

Yes. The base idea is:

```
select
    p.personID,
    p.personName,
    g.grade,
    c.classID,
    c.className
from grades g 
inner join persons p on p.personID = g.personID
inner join classes c on c.classID = g.classID
```

This assumes the following data structures:

```
persons: 
    personID
    personName

classes:
    classID
    className

grades:
    personID   --> foreign key to persons(personID)
    grade
    classID    --> foreign key to classes(classID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from 
gradeTable g
JOIN 
personTable p 
ON g.PersonID = p.PersonID
JOIN 
classTable c
ON g.ClassID = c.ClassID
```